# Best way to navigate through panels on webpage using single next button as navigation

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I've got a number of asp.net panels within a div, and a single "next" asp net button as the bottom of the page, i was wondering what the best possible way to get the button navigating through each of them would be.

Page layout:

```
<container div>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo1" runat="server">
     <div>
       Content
     </div>
   </asp:Panel>
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo2" runat="server">
     <div>
       Content
     </div>
   </asp:Panel>
   --- Several more panels
 </container div>
 <div just for the button>
    <asp:Button ID="btnInfoNext" runat="server" Text="Next" />
 </div just for the button>
```

I'm not entirely sure what the best way to get this up and running would be.

What i'm looking for is a way to get the single button navigating through each of my panels, and hiding the one that was previously active

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest but off the top of my head you could try something along these lines.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInfoNext" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClientClick="nextPanel() />

<script>

function nextPanel()
{
    var panelNumber = sessionStorage.getItem("PanelNumber");

    if(panelNumber === "")
    {
       $('#pnlInfo1').fadeOut('slow');
       $('#pnlInfo2').fadeIn('slow');

       sessionStorage.PanelNumber = 2;
    } 
    else
    {
       var panel = "pnlInfo" + panelNumber + 1;
       var previousPanel = "pnlInfo" + panelNumber - 1;

       $('#' + panel).fadeIn('slow');
       $('#' + previousPanel ).fadeOut('slow');

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not really what i'm looking for, preferably a solution in VB. It will also need to account for more panels, yours only supports 2

Comment: @Bob the above accounts for infinite panels :)